# How to access autogenerated buttons in gridview in RowDataBound event at server side

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view which has two autogenerated Edit and delete buttons in first cell itself. The code is as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdStudent" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AutoGenerateEditButton="true"
    OnRowDeleting="grdStudent_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="grdStudent_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="EditGrid" OnRowCancelingEdit="CancelEdit" OnRowUpdating="UpdateGrid"
    ForeColor="#333333" CellPadding="4" GridLines="Both" Width="90%"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" AllowPaging="True"
    EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="false">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center"
        VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333"
        BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("first_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstName" Text='<%#Eval("first_name") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("last_name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLastName" Text='<%#Eval("last_name") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact No">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblContactNo" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("phone_no") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtContactNo" Text='<%#Eval("phone_no") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmail" Text='<%#Eval("email") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("address") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAddress" Text='<%#Eval("address") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <%-- <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="IsActive" />--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IsActive">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblIsActive" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("active") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <select id="ddlIsActive" class="dropdown" runat="server">
                    <option value="1">True</option>
                    <option value="2">False</option>
                </select>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Username">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtUsername" Text='<%#Eval("username") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Password">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("password") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPassword" Text='<%#Eval("password") %>' Width="100px"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <%--<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" --%>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I need to access the delete button in Row Data bound event and add a confirmation attribute to it. I tried the below code but only Edit button is accessed at server side.

```
protected void grdStudent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != grdStudent.EditIndex)
    {
        string text = ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0]).Text;
        //text always has the value as "Edit" never "Delete"
        if (text == "delete")
        {
            (e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to edit this row?');";
            //del.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you certain you want to delete the record?');";
        }
    }
    //    (e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to edit this row?');";
    //    //(e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[1] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');";
    //}
    //if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex == grdStudent.EditIndex)
    //{
    //    (e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton).Attributes["onclick"] = "return confirm('Do you want to edit this row?');";
    //}
}
```

How can I access Delete button and add a confirmation message box.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the attributes as a key/value pair.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    LinkButton lbEdit = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0] as LinkButton;
    lbEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Do you want to edit this row?');");

    LinkButton lbDelete = e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2] as LinkButton;
    lbDelete.Attributes.Add("onclick","return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[@VDWWD's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44804846/296861) should solve the original problem.

These days, I *personally* like to use icon/font to look more professional.

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridViewDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.GridViewDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <br />
        <div class="container">
            <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdStudent"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                OnRowEditing="grdStudent_RowEditing"
                OnRowDeleting="grdStudent_RowDeleting"
                OnRowDataBound="grdStudent_RowDataBound"
                CssClass="table">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="EditLinkButton" CommandName="Edit">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="DeleteLinkButton" CommandName="Delete">
                                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class GridViewDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                grdStudent.DataSource = Collection;
                grdStudent.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void grdStudent_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                var d = e.Row.FindControl("DeleteLinkButton") as LinkButton;
                d.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?');");
            }
        }

        protected void grdStudent_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e){}

        protected void grdStudent_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e){}

        public class Item
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public static IList<Item> Collection = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item {Id = 1, Name = "One"},
            new Item {Id = 2, Name = "Two"},
            new Item {Id = 3, Name = "Three"}
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work better for confirmation message box at `Client` side:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // reference the Delete LinkButton
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[2];

    if (lb.Text == "Delete")
    {
        lb.OnClientClick = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this row?');";
    }
}
```